# How can I implement a Timer/TimerTask that executes an AsyncTask? (Android)

Tags: android, multithreading, timer, android-asynctask, timertask

I'm trying to perform a task (ie. load data from a text file) asynchronously and repeatedly at specified times (ie. every few seconds, though this rate may change at runtime).

I have done some research and decided that this will require either an AsyncTask or a separate Thread.  I have decided to use an AsyncTask for simplicity.

I now need to execute this AsyncTask according to a repeating timer schedule.  I believe I must make use of a Timer and a TimerTask.

The code below is a simple form of what I am trying to achieve.  When I try to run this code using an Android emulator (through the Eclipse IDE) I get the following message: "Sorry!  The application has stopped unexpectedly.  Please try again."

I would like to know where the problem arises and how I can fix it.  Thanks!

```
public class Sample extends Activity {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    SimpleTimerTask myTimerTask = new SimpleTimerTask(); 

    long delay = 0;
    long period = 5000;

    Timer myTimer = new Timer();
    myTimer.schedule(myTimerTask, delay, period);
}


private class SimpleAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return null;
    }   
}


private class SimpleTimerTask extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {
        new SimpleAsyncTask().execute();
    }       
}

}
```

EDIT: Here are the LogCat Messages that seem to be relevant

FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

at ...

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

at ...

Comment: What does the log in logcat say? You'll probably find a stacktrace there, and it indicates your problem.

Comment: @Kaj - This is a very helpful comment (for beginner Android developers like myself at least).  I didn't even know what LogCat was but now I see its value for debugging/error tracing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're making this way harder than it needs to be.  The `TimerTask` already runs on it's own thread, so you don't need to use an `AsyncTask` just put the code you want to run in the `TimerTask.run()` method.

Comment: Interesting.  I definitely like this solution better as its way simpler.  I just need to figure out how I can update the UI from the TimerTask thread now... any ideas?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can pass in a `Handler` to send `Messages` to the UI Thread.

Answer (score 0):

There is a serious limitation of using timertask with asynctask if you want to update UI from OnPostExecute method. A timer is run in separate thread, so you have to find a way to start an asynctask from main thread.